# How to differentiate between Terminal scripted launch and manual launch for .bash_profile settings

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

I have some `.bash_profile` settings that restore my last working directory every time I log in to my shell. However, I also use a program that opens a terminal window in the current directory open in Finder, and it does this by sending an event to Terminal using [SBApplication](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/SBApplication_Class/).

Is there a way I can detect which way the Terminal was opened in my `.bash_profile`? Right now the bash settings override the [cd to](https://github.com/jbtule/cdto) app.

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.4
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin"
export PATH

# My settings
trap 'printf %s "$PWD" > ~/.storepwd' EXIT

cd "$(<~/.storepwd)"
```

Comment: Please edit your question adding the settings you've added to your `.bash_profile` that are relevant to this question.

Comment: Please add an answer instead of editing a solution into your question. You might add it to the accepted answer or the user jherran can do it

Comment: BTW "PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin" ... 
export PATH" will probably break your PATH

Comment: @klanomath thanks, new to this site. Yes, I quickly edited out some stuff in my path that I didn't think was relevant to the question and forgot to leave the :${PATH} at the end :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display [BASH variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html) on your `.bash_profile`. Then compare the output when you manually open the terminal with output when [cd to](https://github.com/jbtule/cdto) app opens the terminal.

I meant append at the beginning of your `.bash_profile` the bash variables listed on the website:

```
echo $BASH
echo $BASHOPTS
echo $BASHPID
...
echo $TMPDIR
echo $UID
```

Then open manually the terminal and save the output.
Open the terminal from cd to and save the output.

Compare the files.

---

The proper variable for the above example is DIRSTACK.

Here are the new settings for those passing through:

```
# My settings
if [ $DIRSTACK = "~" ]; then
    trap 'printf %s "$PWD" > ~/.storepwd' EXIT
    cd "$(<~/.storepwd)"
fi
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on this, maybe include a working example too?

Comment: `BASHOPTS` isn't set in the standard `bash` on OSX.

Comment: Thanks @jherran! The variable I was looking for is $DIRSTACK.